# How do I attach an error attribute to a function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gcc

I am trying to deprecate a function in a library. But instead of warning developers that the function is deprecated, I want to attach a build error to the function so that developers switch over to the new work flow. I now that for a method you can have a deprecated attribute:

```
- (void)methodName __attribute((deprecated));
```

But when I try to attach the error attribute from [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes), Xcode gives me a warning saying "Unknown attribute 'error' ignored"

```
- (void)methodName __attribute((error));
```

How do I attach the error to the function?

Comment: If you want an error with the old API, simply remove the old API so it can't be used.

Comment: Yes, but I want to point them in the direction of the new flow by using the message option that __attribute__ gives.

Comment: How about commenting out the method names in the headers and adding a comment above each one to point the users to the new API?